# How to reference multiple fields? eg. "$$ROOT.field.$$id" - FieldPath field names may not start with '$'

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to figure out how to reference a field using a variable...

**What I am trying to do:**

I have an array of categories in one field with an ids field (array) in it, and a field (dictionary) where the keys are an id from these arrays.

I am trying to map the array of ids in each category into the values in the dictionary.

What I am starting with is something like this:

```
Document {
    "categories": [
      {"name": "One", "ids": [4, 7]},
      {"name": "Two", "ids": [7]}
    ],
    "data": {
      4: {"name": "John"},
      7: {"name": "Nick"},
      2: {"name": "Oliver"}
    }
}
```

And the result I am looking for is something like this:

```
{
    "One": [
        {"name": "John"},
        {"name": "Nick"}
    ],
    "Two": [
        {"name": "Nick"}
    ]
}
```

What I tried doing at first was the straight-forward solution that failed me...

```
"$replaceWith": {
    "$arrayToObject": {
        "$map": {
            "input": "$$ROOT.categories",
            "in": {
                "k": "$$this.name",
                "v": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$$this.ids",
                        "as": "id",
                        "in": "$$ROOT.data.$$id"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Which didn't work... (Playground link)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fv7U5kQyiF0)
I got the "FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField." error.

I then also tried using "$getField" like I was suggested but the expression given there must be a constant.

From there I tried finding a solution on Google but couldn't find anything. I decided to resort to using "$function":

```
"$replaceWith": {
    "$arrayToObject": {
        "$map": {
            "input": "$$ROOT.categories",
            "in": {
                "k": "$$this.name",
                "v": {
                    "$map": {
                        "input": "$$this.ids",
                        "as": "id",
                        "in": {
                            "$function": {
                                "body": "function(id, data) {return data[id]}",
                                "args": [
                                    "$$id",
                                    "$$ROOT.data"
                                ],
                                "lang": "js"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Which worked. (Playground link)](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KWDfD5-GfIi)

But, since I believe that '$function' isn't as efficient and also due to my curiosity, I would like to know if there is a better solution to my problem.

Thanks!

#### EDIT

I just found out that PyMongo doesn't support '$function' so I definitely would love some help.

Comment: you need to change schema, you can do those in MongoDB without `$function` but it will be complicated and slow. You shouldn't use data on fields, fields are for the schema, MongoDB query language doesn't work with dynamic keys, to make it work you do complicated and slow things.

Comment: I don't see filtering here...?   If you're not filtering and you need a whole doc worth of data to perform the transform you seek, easier to just get the doc client-side into a programming language and use 2 for loops and a hash and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Query

- the problem is that in MongoDB we cant until now at least use dynamic fields, for example we don't have a `get(myDoc, $$akey)`
- a way to do it in MongoDB aggregation with objectToArray and back to object
- query is so big, slow, and even if you try to make it smaller(probably its possible) it will be still be so complicated for the simple thing you wanted to do
- you need to change schema, no matter how better you write that it will still be complicated and slow

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70637054-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":{"data-arr":{"$objectToArray":"$data"}}},
 {"$project":
  {"categories":
   {"$map":
    {"input":"$categories",
     "in":
     {"$let":
      {"vars":
       {"d":
        {"$map":
         {"input":{"$objectToArray":"$$this"},
          "in":["$$this.k", "$$this.v"]}}},
       "in":
       {"$let":
        {"vars":
         {"k":{"$arrayElemAt":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$$d", 0]}, 1]},
          "v":{"$arrayElemAt":[{"$arrayElemAt":["$$d", 1]}, 1]}},
         "in":
         {"k":"$$k",
          "v":
          {"$map":
           {"input":"$$v",
            "in":
            {"$first":
             {"$filter":
              {"input":
               {"$map":
                {"input":"$data-arr",
                 "in":
                 {"$cond":
                  [{"$eq":[{"$toString":"$$this"}, "$$dk.k"]},
                   "$$dk.v", null]},
                 "as":"dk"}},
               "cond":{"$ne":["$$p", null]},
               "as":"p"}}}}}}}}}}}}}},
 {"$set":{"categories":{"$arrayToObject":["$categories"]}}},
 {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$categories"}}])
```